# Controlling Content-Type from REST service

Tags: content-type, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-starter-kit

I working on a REST service based on the 'WCF REST Service template' in VS2010. Out-of-the-box, you can have a service return XML or JSON, based on the Accept type specified in the request, but how do I add my own format....
I found an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx

where you test the Accept header in the method, and return Message based on that type, however I don't really like to implement this in all my service methods.

What I'd really like is a way where I could annotate (attribute) my DataContract with a formatter/serializer for each kind of Content-Type that I want to support, and then framework call my formatter/serialiser when asked for a Content-Type not supported out-of-the-box.

Are there already some extensionpoints, in the WCF REST Service framework, for doing this??

Any help would be greatly appreciated
TIA

Søren

Answer (score 0):

[WcfRestContrib should be able to do this via Formatters](https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib/wiki/De-serialization-Overview). It provides set of build in formatters for XML, JSON, URL encoded form posts and it also allows creating custom formatters.

Built in `webHttpBinding` in WCF doesn't have this functionality at the moment - it allows only `appliation/json` and `text/xml` negotiation and other content types can be mapped to these two via [custom content type mapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943479.aspx).

"Attributes" for response formatting are only available for syndication where it works little bit differently. Service must always return `SyndicationFeedFormatter` and known types allow defining multiple derived formatters for Atom or Rss.